Upload multiple file objects to API as 2d array of files
I am trying to build an API using django which support file uploads as an array of array. An example of what I am trying to achieve is,
[
    {
        "string": "Some string",
        "files": [
            "<uploaded file object 1>",
            "<uploaded file object 2>"
        ]
    },
    {
        "string": "Some string",
        "files": [
            "<uploaded file object 3>"
        ]
    },
    {
        "string": "Some string",
        "files": []
    }
]

I dont want to use base64 encoded files for this since the files can be sometimes large, so I dont want to increase the overheads using base64.
**how can I achieve this API call in the most efficient way and what would be most appropriate structure to call this API and help with some javascript frontend code do it.
**
I tried to move this to a FormData where I can acheive the a above upload like below but I am not able to call the API from the frontend, it doesnt work probably because I am writing wrong code.
strings: ["Some string", "Some string", "Some string"]
files: [["<uploaded file object 1>", "<uploaded file object 2>"], ["<uploaded file object 3>"]]

For my backend I am using django(rest framework), here is the relevant part of the serializer if required
class StringSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    serializers = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
    files = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField()),
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
        allow_empty=True,
        default=[],
    )



What you're trying to do looks like it would be quite awkward, especially given Django's current lack of features for file upload handling... "Django is likely to have a proper multiple file field support at some point in the future."

Sample codes using formData, Frontend and backend (express)
Frontend coding highlights:
a. blob object has been created to conceive the file content. Refer to the statement: stmt-1.
b. The property string has been used to set the key in formData object.
c. Each blob object in the array has been added to formData individually.
For both of the above two points, refer to the statement: stmt-2.
d. The API has been called inside the hook useEffect. Refer to the statement: stmt-3.
e. The upload status has been updated to the state variable. Refer to the statement: stmt-4.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState('');

  const someContent = '<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>';
  const blob = new Blob([someContent], { type: 'text/xml' }); // stmt 1
  const data = [
    {
      string: 'Somestring1',
      files: [blob, blob],
    },
    {
      string: 'Somestring2',
      files: [blob],
    },
    {
      string: 'Somestring3',
      files: [blob],
    },
  ];

  const formData = new FormData();
  data.forEach((rec) => {
    rec.files.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append(rec.string, file); // stmt-2
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => setUploadStatus(data)); // stmt-4
  }, []); // stmt-3

  return 'Upload Status : ' + (uploadStatus ? uploadStatus : 'Unknown');
}

Backend - Express using multer middleware
Coding highlights
a. The multipart-formdata in the frontend code has been received by the nodejs middleware multer. For more about multer, please see the page https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');
const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads',
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/upload', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send('success');
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Listening...');
});

Trial run:
By running the frontend code, the files will be uploaded automatically, and the at the backend server, server console logs will be created as below.
[
  {
    fieldname: 'Somestring1',
    originalname: 'blob',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'text/xml',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: 'f94460f91f497bac0c1e0fdc4292eadc',
    path: 'uploads/f94460f91f497bac0c1e0fdc4292eadc',
    size: 38
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'Somestring1',
    originalname: 'blob',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'text/xml',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: 'deb237a854b4027a9e106effc236343d',
    path: 'uploads/deb237a854b4027a9e106effc236343d',
    size: 38
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'Somestring2',
    originalname: 'blob',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'text/xml',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: '52fd4e96f278f216f339be0f72ce1b6f',
    path: 'uploads/52fd4e96f278f216f339be0f72ce1b6f',
    size: 38
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'Somestring3',
    originalname: 'blob',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'text/xml',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: '781e6d3bbf3fb01149fa7fd8e428339d',
    path: 'uploads/781e6d3bbf3fb01149fa7fd8e428339d',
    size: 38
  }
]

The uploads folder in the backend will have the uploaded files. The list of it has been enclosed below.


OP is clearly using a Python-based backend (Django). What is the point of including Express / Multer code in your answer?

@Phil, Extremely for that, I was hoping it may provide some help.

Keying by the string property also looks problematic, especially given the repeated values in OP's example. I think you should familiarise yourself with Django's file handling capabilities before offering incorrect advice - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/http/file-uploads/
